# C# - error in object construction syntax

Tags: c#, object, constructor

I'm trying to create an object using the provided constructor, but I'm not entirely sure how I can utilize it.

So, the class constructor is:

```
public Scheduler(CPU[] cpus, TimeSpan tick, (SimulatedProgram program, Priority priority, CPU[] affinities)[] programs)
```

And when I try to initialize an object of class Scheduler like this:

```
Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler(new CPU[] { cpu0, cpu1 }, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), (program0, Priority.Normal, new CPU[] { cpu0, cpu1 }));
```

I get the `(program0, Priority.Normal, new CPU[] { cpu0, cpu1 })` part underlined with error:

> Error CS1503 Argument 3:
>   cannot convert from '(SimCPULibrary.SimulatedProgram, SimCPULibrary.Priority, SimCPULibrary.CPU[])' to '(SimulatedProgram program, Priority priority, CPU[] affinities)[]' DllConsoleTest

Comment: Looks like the third argument should be an array as well. `new[]{(program0, Priority.Normal, new CPU[] { cpu0, cpu1 })}`

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Comment: @mjwills It's a Tuple, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt493248.aspx

Comment: looks like you need to pass an array of tuple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this subject by any means but I do notice one thing that may help.

In the class constructor **Parameter 3** is

```
(SimulatedProgram program, Priority priority, CPU[] affinities)[] programs
```

The argument that you are trying to pass in looks almost the same except for one noticable difference. You are passing in a single entity, where the constructor calls for **an array of entities**.

Instead of passing in `(program0, Priority.Normal, new CPU[] { cpu0, cpu1 })` I suggest doing something more like this...

```
new[] { (program0, Priority.Normal, new CPU[] { cpu0, cpu1 }) }
```

I look forward to hearing if this helped at all or not, as I mentioned already, I am by no means an expert, so if there is someone who has an explanation that ranges further than the one I am able to provide then I suggest prioritizing their answer.

Comment: This answer sounds correct, but your code example has a typo.  You are missing the opening `(` of the tuple inside the array initializer.  Normally, you also do not need to specify the type of the array between `new` and `[]` if it can be inferred from the array contents between `{` and `}`.  I'm not sure if this applies in this situation, but it would make it a lot more readable.